# Closing the gap

Tags: faces, edges

This is one thing that sometimes stumps me, but what is the best way of closing the gap here and keeping everything in Quads?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In edit mode using edges <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> the loop to select it.
[image]

Then press <kbd>space</kbd> and enter "grid" click on the "grid fill"
[image]

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that feature existed. That's solved it. :D

Comment: @DustyShinigami   You'll find that Grid Fill doesn't like an odd number of edges, and doesn't tell you that's why it's not working.. just one to look out for...

Answer (score 5):

[image: Closing off a Triangle Fan Cylinder with Quads by deleting every other Row of Vertices]
Another gold standard that works with even numbers of vertices is to

- Select the Edge Loop
- Extrude Edge Loop, stop Transform with Right Click
- Merge the extruded Vertices at Center
- Select every other Edge
- Dissolve Edges

Comment: your last frame only lasts 200ms so we can not see the result before the GIF anim starts again.

Comment: I am amazed how you knew it only lasted 200ms, but I will fix it of course. :D

Comment: 5 seconds of all quad topology!

Comment: As an aside, how do you make little gifs like that?

Comment: You need some kind of screen-capture software. I use Techsmith SnagIt - think of it as Camtasia's uncomplicated little brother - to record what you are doing. Then you cut out the fluff and export the video as a GIF sequence. That usually takes some fiddling with compression due to the size constraints.

Comment: I should add, there are free alternatives, like ScreenToGif and Recordit, I just haven't used them. My colleagues do though, and they do a fine job.